# Eclipse Kepler, PMD5 trouble

Tags: eclipse, pmd, eclipse-kepler

﻿I have installed plugin PMD5 with this page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/... in eclipse kepler.

When I try to import my own xml file also in version 5, "ok" button is inactive. What is it? what is wrong? I've tried different methods and still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

In my windows xp 32 bit when installing the PMD with this page: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/
the latest version of PMD which is installed this is 5.05. 
Although it is already version 5.1, I do not know why not being installed in my Eclipse Kepler....... in version PMD 5.1, only 5.05.

In my xml file occurs line:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/UseUtilityClass" />
```

Before we released version 5.1, used the name UseSingleton. In version 5.1 the name  changed on UseUtilityClass.

A summary:
In version  PMD 5.05 line should look like this:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/UseSingleton" />
```

Above version  PMD 5.1 line should look like this:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/UseUtilityClass" />
```